# Closed-form solution of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+ax)^{(1+m)}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to know whether there is a closed form solution for the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+ax)^{(1+m)}}\,dx$$
where $a$ and $m$ are positive (not necessarily integers).

A closed-form solution can be found for the very specific case of $a=1$ for the above integral, i.e., $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+x)^{(1+m)}}\,dx = B(1,m) \cdot [\psi(1+m) - \psi(m)]$, where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Beta function and $\psi(\cdot)$ is the Euler psi function.

But I want to know whether there is a solution for the general case. If there is not, is there a way to represent the integral approximately with a closed form expression (or in terms of hypergeometric functions).

I have tried to express the nominator and denominator using Meijer-G functions and employ the convolution theorem (the product of two arbitrary G-functions integrated over the positive real axis can be represented by just another G-function), but it turns out there are too many strict constraints to employ the theorem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a>0$ and $a\not =1$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}, m\geq 1$.

We use integration by parts:

$$F_m(a)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+x)}{(1+ax)^{m+1}}dx=\big[-\frac{\log(1+x)}{am(1+ax)^m}\big]_0^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{ma}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(1+ax)^m}$$

Hence
$$maF_m(a)=G_m(a)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(1+ax)^m}$$

Now put $\displaystyle R(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)(1+ax)^m}$. We have
$$R(x)=\frac{1}{(1-a)^m(1+x)}-\frac{a}{1-a}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{(1-a)^k(1+ax)^{m-k}}$$

and hence
$$G_m(a)=-\frac{\log a}{(1-a)^m}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{(m-k-1)(1-a)^{k+1}}$$

Comment: @Ron Gordon After verification, you are saying that $(1+ax)^{(m+1)}$ is not $ (1+ax)$ to the power $m+1$, is it that ?

Comment: I have verified my answer carefully, but a computational error is always possible,; this is what I mean.

Comment: @Kelenner . Hi Kelenner. Thanks a lot for the contribution. I can see that you have assumed $m$ is an integer in the derivation. But how about $m$ is only positive?

Comment: @Vic: I do not know. The integral formula for $G_m(a)$ is true without assuming $m$ an integer, but $R(x)$ is not a rational function, so this is more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it is true that $G_{m}(a)$ is valid without assuming $m$ an integer. Then, starting from the integral $G_{m}(a)$ in your derivation, using the equality $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\upsilon-1} (\beta + x)^{-\mu} (x+\gamma)^{-\varrho} \, dx = \beta^{-\mu} \gamma^{\upsilon-\varrho} B(\upsilon,\mu-\upsilon+\varrho) {}_{2}F_{1}(\mu,\upsilon;\mu+\varrho;1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})$ [$|\arg \beta| < \pi$, $|\arg \gamma| < \pi$, $\textrm{Re}\, {\upsilon}>0$, $\textrm{Re}\, {\mu} >  \textrm{Re}\, {(\upsilon-\varrho)}$], we will get a solution in terms of Beta function and hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

> $I=\dfrac{B\bigg(1-\dfrac1a~;~m~;~1-m\bigg)}{m~a~(a-1)^m}~:~$ See [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) for more information.

In particular, for integer and half-integer values of *m* we have the following results:

> $$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{(A+ax)^2}~dx~=~\dfrac{2\ln\sqrt{\dfrac Aa}}{a~(A-a)}$$
>
> $$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{(A+ax)^{3/2}}~dx~=~\dfrac{4\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac Aa}}{a~(a-A)}$$

from which the others can be evaluated by repeatedly differentiating both sides with regard to *A*, and then setting $A=1$.

Comment: Hi, Lucian . Thanks a lot for the contribution. I got a solution in terms of Beta function and hypergeometric function ${}_{2}F_{1}(\cdot, \cdot; \cdot; \cdot)$ following @Kelenner derivation shown below. The solution is$I = \frac{1}{m*a^2} B(1,m){}_{2}F_{1}(1,1;1+m;1-\frac{1}{a})$. Your solution is not that obvious for me since in the incomplete beta function B(x;a,b), the integration limit is from $0$ to $x$.